# MVC 2 - URL Shortening/ Routing (Map Route)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-shortener

I have a URL: http://localhost:XXXX/Details/569

I want to shorten it to: http://localhost:XXXX/569

Currently I have:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

So what changes do I do in my routes so that when an integer value is entered, it goes to my Details function in the HomeController:

```
public ActionResult Details(int recordID)
{
    /** Code Here **/
    return View();
}
```

**EDIT: Catching Errors**

Also how can I catch for any error that happens in the application? Rather than display an error dump, I would like to show a "nice" message that says, "Oops! Something Broke!".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this route before the default one. It will make sure the URLs containing only numbers calls HomeController's Details action.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "RecordDetails",
    "xxxx/{RecordID}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Details", RecordID=0 },
    new { RecordID = @"\d+" });
```

Comment: Hi Ufukh. Thanks for the reply. I tried your solution but I got the following errors. They are: Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /10

Comment: Thanks so much Ufuk. That worked. Now it goes straight to the Details function by default and not to the Index function. Is there a way to have it go to the Details function only if the URL is http://localhost:XXXX/{SOME NUMBER HERE}?

Comment: Sure there is. I've updated the route. Replace "xxxx" with whatever needed

Comment: In the case @DerekColt gave, removal of the "xxxx/" is probably fine. So in the end you just have "{RecordID}". That shortened it up on my application nicely and is all I needed to change for this example to work for me.